# What does the function $f = \frac{1}{(\;(\frac{1}x)^{1000}+ (\frac{1}y)^{1000}\;)^{1/1000}}$ represent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I was asked during an interview for an AI company that what do you think the following function represents.
>
> $$
> f = \frac{1}{(\;(\frac{1}x)^{1000}+ (\frac{1}y)^{1000}\;)^{1/1000}} 
> $$

I answered initially that it behaves like an OR gate?!!?!? to which the interviewer replied its a more generic thing.

Is it some filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we to assume $x,y \gt 0?$  You should confirm this.  If so, note that the larger of $\frac 1x$ and $\frac 1y$ will dominate the sum in the denominator because of the $1000$ power.  The $\frac 1{1000}$ power will remove it, so the denominator is roughly $\max(\frac 1x,\frac 1y)$.  We invert that and get $\min (x,y)$

Comment: Actually because $x$ and $y$ are raised to the $1000$th power, we don't need to assume the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @ilovebulbasaur:  True.  See my comment to your answer, which crossed in the internet with yours.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what your interviewer was looking for: we have
$$\begin{align*}\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}(|a|^{p}+|b|^p)^{1/p}=\max\{|a|,|b|\}\end{align*}.$$
So in your case, for $p=1000$ large we approximately have
$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{((\frac{1}{x})^{1000}+(\frac{1}{y})^{1000})^{1/1000}}&\approx\frac{1}{\max\{\frac{1}{|x|},\frac{1}{|y|}\}}\\ &=\min\{|x|,|y|\}.
\end{align*}.$$

Comment: Great minds think alike.  I would use parentheses instead of braces, but otherwise your approach to negative arguments is more accurate (though perhaps less effective in an interview setting) than mine. +1

Comment: It's what I would have stated if I myself was the interviewee. Also, for marginal bonus points on the interview, it's worth pointing out fixing $y\neq 0$ and taking $x\downarrow 0$ on both sides of the equation, the result still holds.

Comment: By the way, do you know the intention behind asking this question from the OP in the interview? How does it relate to being a person who can handle AI?

Comment: Okay, what does the min function do, any application? Well not really, at this point he was rushing through things.

Comment: @Jin More likely it's a test of quantitative reasoning than anything else.

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh It may not be directly related to AI per se, but if this is a quantitative research position where a majority of applicants have PhD's in math or CS, then I think this question helps distinguish who's better.

Comment: hmm no. it was for an entry-level data analyst position in AI production

Comment: Then probably just one of the curveball questions they throw at people to see who's more clever :p.

Comment: Nice +1. Maybe more precisely, not hard to see $$x \geqslant y> 0\implies y>\frac1{\left(\left(\frac1y\right)^{1000} + \left(\frac1x\right)^{1000} \right)^{1/1000}} \geqslant (1+1)^{-1/1000} y > 0.999y$$